# ROS2 (Python) Timer callback only calling once when I call spin_once( ) within it

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, ros, ros2

I have a ros2 callback that I'd like to call once a second, which makes several service calls to check the state of another part of the system. Unfortunately, when I include asynchronous service calls (with a small block to wait for a result) the timer callback still finishes, but does not run again. The code is below, and I'm using ROS2 version 'Humble'

Any help would be hugely appreciated

```
import time
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.executors import MultiThreadedExecutor
from rclpy.callback_groups import MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup, ReentrantCallbackGroup
from container_interfaces.srv import ReadPLCBool, ReadPLCInt, WritePLCBool, WritePLCInt

from plc_module.utils import error_codes, plc_variables

class MonitorNode(Node):
    
    PLC_POLL_FREQUENCY = 1.0          # How often to poll the PLC to check if a tray has moved into place (in seconds)
                                    
    PLC_SERVICES_TIMEOUT = 10       # How long to wait for the plc services to respond to a request (in seconds) - these are pretty simple services so we shouldn't wait this long unless something has gone wrong
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        
        # Call the constructor for the Node class
        super().__init__('monitor')        
        
        # Create various callback groups to ensure that the various services are called in a mutually exclusive manner
        self.plc_reader_callbackgroup = MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup()
        
        # Create various clients to interface with the PLC services - if any of these fail to connect the node will not be able to function,
        # so we kill the node immediately if this happens - better than allowing it to run until it tries to access a broken service and crashes
        self._logger.debug("Creating read bool service client")
        self.read_bool_client = self.create_client(ReadPLCBool, 'read_plc_bool', callback_group=self.plc_reader_callbackgroup)
        try:
            self.read_bool_client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=10)
            self._logger.info("Read bool service client created")
        except:
            self._logger.fatal("'read_plc_bool' service not ready within 10s timeout - is it running?")
            self.destroy_node()
            exit()
        
        # Create a timer to periodically check the state of the PLC and trigger the other modules if necessary
        self.plc_monitor_timer = self.create_timer(self.PLC_POLL_FREQUENCY, self.plc_monitor_callback)
        
       

   def plc_monitor_callback(self) -> bool:
        
        self._logger.info("plc_monitor_callback called")

        request = ReadPLCBool.Request()
        request.data_block = 36
        request.byte_index = 12
        request.bit_index = 1
        
        future = self.read_bool_client.call_async(request)
        
        self._logger.info("Made asynchronous call") 

        while rclpy.ok():
            rclpy.spin_once(self)
            if future.done():
                self._logger.info("Asynchronous call finished")
                try:
                    response = future.result()
                except Exception as e:
                    self.get_logger().error("Service call failed %r" % (e,))
                    break
                else:
                    self._logger.info("Got response: {}".format(response.value))
                    break
                
        self._logger.info("plc_monitor_callback finished")
    
        return 

def main(args=None):
    
    # Create an instance of the node and spin it
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    monitor = MonitorNode()
    
    try:
        rclpy.spin(monitor)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    feed_initialiser.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this code I see all the printed messages up to and including 'plc_monitor_callback finished', but nothing afterwards. The 'read_plc_bool' service is running as expected in another node, and continues to be callable after my monitor node hangs - at the moment it's running in a separate terminal window although the plan is to run these both from a launch file.

I've tried setting up different configurations of callback groups and executors, as well as using synchronous calls to this service, although these attempts don't seem to help.

Comment: In case it's relevant - the service 'read_plc_bool' doesn't require any other nested service calls - it simply sends a tcp packet and parses the response

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this same problem down the line:

I've managed to work around this by removing the block beginning 'while rclpy.ok( ):' and replacing it with the following:

```
future = self.read_bool_client.call_async(request)    
self._logger.info("Made asynchronous call") 
future.add_done_callback(self.some_new_callback)
```

Where the new callback takes over the next step in execution - I'd still be interested to hear if there's some way of executing this in a single sequential callback, although this may contravene the general ROS principle of not using synchronous callbacks nested within other callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Hopping into the conversation a bit late, but here's a good idea with threads for anyone seeing this later:

```py
import threading
... # do the same stuff as you have done until any spin call
   def plc_monitor_callback(self) -> bool:
        
        self._logger.info("plc_monitor_callback called")

        request = ReadPLCBool.Request()
        request.data_block = 36
        request.byte_index = 12
        request.bit_index = 1
        
        future = self.read_bool_client.call_async(request)
        
        self._logger.info("Made asynchronous call") 

        while rclpy.ok(): # not a very good idea to use this one in a callback
            # rclpy.spin_once(self) # we don't really want this
            if future.done():
                self._logger.info("Asynchronous call finished")
                try:
                    response = future.result()
                except Exception as e:
                    self.get_logger().error("Service call failed %r" % (e,))
                    # make sure the break statement is called quickly
                    break 
                else:
                    self._logger.info("Got response: {}".format(response.value))
                    # make sure the break statement is called quickly
                    break
                
        self._logger.info("plc_monitor_callback finished")
    
        return 
def main(args=None):
    
    # Create an instance of the node and spin it
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    monitor = MonitorNode()

    # Spin in a separate thread
    monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=rclpy.spin, args=(MonitorNode, ), daemon=True)
    monitor_thread.start()

    # # Seems like you are using ctrl+c to kill your node spinner, it will still do it now
    # try:
    #     rclpy.spin(monitor)
    # except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #     pass
    while rclpy.ok():
      pass # you can even pass some kind of a rate.sleep here now that your spinner is threaded
    monitor_thread.join() 
    feed_initialiser.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
```

The idea is that NOT calling `rclpy.spin` or its variants frequently blocks your callbacks. This is because whatever timer you are using depends on a spinner to be called in the first place, i.e. your `self.create_timer` won't be very stable if you are progressing the timer by yourself within its callback.
In ROS 2, you are kind of responsible for the proper checking for callbacks in a non-blocking fashion (from how I get it, back in ROS 1, calling any time-related thing along with asking for a spin or is_shutdown did the job of checking for callbacks for you, with the small incurred risk of you blocking your callbacks)
EDIT: another thing to note is that I've added spin as a separate thread, so you need some kind of a while loop to keep things running in the background (e.g. `while rclpy.ok():`)
EDIT: You also shouldn't stay too long in a callback as a rule of thumb. Make sure you break out of the while loop quickly.
Also, a small note - you don't need to explicitly call shutdown at the end of your script, though it doesn't hurt to do so. I also personally join my threads and shut the ros client down.